# TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python

So, I was trying to make code for a Pokédex, and I have the following section of code set to print out the stats of a Pokémon. Note that there are 715 other dictionaries before these three:

```
Xerneas = {'HP': 126, 'Atk': 131, 'Def': 95, 'SAtk': 131, 'SDef': 98, 'Spd': 99,
           'Ability': "Fairy Aura", 'Type': "Fairy"}
Yveltal = {'HP': 126, 'Atk': 131, 'Def': 95, 'SAtk': 131, 'SDef': 98, 'Spd': 99,
           'Ability': "Dark Aura", 'Type': "Dark/Flying"}
Zygarde = {'HP': 108, 'Atk': 100, 'Def': 121, 'SAtk': 81, 'SDef': 95, 'Spd': 95,
           'Ability': "Aura Break", 'Type': "Dragon/Ground"}

Mode = input('Which mode? ')
if Mode == "Pokedex":
    Pokemon = input("Which Pokemon? ")
    print(Pokemon['HP'],
          Pokemon['Atk'],
          Pokemon['Def'],
          Pokemon['SAtk'],
          Pokemon['SDef'],
          Pokemon['Spd'],
          Pokemon['Ability'],
          Pokemon['Type'])
```

So then I tried running my code and calling Zygarde's information, but the following error came up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Cobalt/Documents/Python/Pokédex.py", line 154, in <module>
    print(Pokemon['HP'],
TypeError: string indices must be integers
>>>
```

Is there an easy solution to this problem? I'm willing to reformat 718 dictionaries if necessary.

By the way, this is my first question on this website, so please don't be too harsh with me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a multidimension array like so

```
pokemon = { 'Xerneas':  {'HP': 126, 'Atk': 131, 'Def': 95, 'SAtk': 131, 'SDef': 98, 'Spd': 99,
           'Ability': "Fairy Aura", 'Type': "Fairy"},
  'Yveltal': {'HP': 126, 'Atk': 131, 'Def': 95, 'SAtk': 131, 'SDef': 98, 'Spd': 99,
           'Ability': "Dark Aura", 'Type': "Dark/Flying"},
  'Zygarde': {'HP': 108, 'Atk': 100, 'Def': 121, 'SAtk': 81, 'SDef': 95, 'Spd': 95,
           'Ability': "Aura Break", 'Type': "Dragon/Ground"}
}
```

Then when you are asking for which pokemon to use:

```
    pokemon_type = input("Which Pokemon? ")
    print(pokemon[pokemon_type]['HP'],
          pokemon[pokemon_type]['Atk'],
          pokemon[pokemon_type]['Def'],
          pokemon[pokemon_type]['SAtk'],
          pokemon[pokemon_type]['SDef'],
          pokemon[pokemon_type]['Spd'],
          pokemon[pokemon_type]['Ability'],
          pokemon[pokemon_type]['Type'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However, when I changed the code into the multidimension array, I got an "invalid syntax error message, which then moved my cursor in between 'yveltal' and the colon. Is there something else wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
Pokemon = input("Which Pokemon? ")
```

This makes `Pokemon` a string. You then attempt to access this string by doing:

```
Pokemon['HP']
```

Now the interpreter complains because `HP` isn't a valid index in the context of a string.
I'm guessing you meant to have a dictionary here?

What you probably want to do is something along the lines of this:

Make a dictionary containing all the pokemon, for example we could call it `pokemon_dict`

```
pokemon_dict = { "xerneas" : Xerneas, .....}

selection = input("Which Pokemon? ")
pokemon_selected = pokemon_dict[selection]
print(pokemon_selected['HP'])
```

Answer (score 1):

This statement

```
Pokemon = input("Which Pokemon? ")
```

sets `Pokemon` to a string.